# Looking for coffee from the 80's for my father, Lucern?

Tags: coffee, history

my dad mentioned today that he loved this coffee he used to get once in a while in the early 80's called Lucerne (not sure about the spelling). He said it was in a white can with red lettering and he couldn't always get it at the local store here is Philadelphia, PA. But when he saw it he would get it. It's fathers day and I would love to find it if it still exists. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help in advance.

-Brad

Comment: This is really a sourcing question, and so off topic:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea

Answer (score 6):

Lucerne is the 'house brand' for Safeway grocery in the USA and can be found at [www.lucernefoods.com](http://www.lucernefoods.com/).

They no longer appear to produce coffee, though I do remember them having done so in the past.